# Incrementing Numbers & Counting with sed syntax

Tags: bash, time, sed, syntax, increment

I am trying to wrap my head around sed and thought it would be best to try using something simple yet useful. At work I want to keep count on a small LCD display each time a specific script is run by users. I am currently doing this with a total count using the following syntax:

```
oldnum=`cut -d ':' -f2 TotalCount.txt`
newnum=`expr $oldnum + 1`
sed -i "s/$oldnum\$/$newnum/g" TotalCount.txt
```

This modifies the file that has this one line in it:

> Total Recordings:0

Now I want to elaborate a little and increment the numbers starting at midnight and resetting to zero at 23:59:59 each day. I created a secondary .txt file for the display to read from with only one single line in it:

> Total Recordings Today:0

But the syntax is not going to be the same. How must the above sed syntax be changed to change the number in the dialog of the second file?

I can change and reset the files using sed/bash in conjunction with a simple cron job on a schedule. The problem is that I can't figure out the syntax of sed to replicate the same effect as I originally got to work. Can anyone help please, I have been reading for hours on this, finally decided to post this and just make a pot of coffee. I have a 4 line LCD and would love to track counts across schedules if it is easy enough to learn the syntax.

Comment: Are you already outputting anything to the LCD, or are you asking how to do it?

Comment: This is already going out to both an LCD and PushBullet notifications, but only that first simple counter. That simply shows the total number of times the command was run (all time since the script has started), I would like to narrow it down by more specific times next.

Comment: So the PushBullet checks the content of your file periodically i'm guessing, or when it changes? As for the script increments and resetting at midnight you could easily do that with a cron job.

Comment: When the file changes a bash script runs that uses the PushBullet API to send a message from a variable pulled from the single line text file. The messages and the LCD are only updated if the script is run and the script is only run if the command is sent. My problem is I that I can't figure out the syntax of sed to modify the little area that I seem to have found some success with. I want it work with other things but can't figure it out. I was hoping if anyone could help I could mess with what the solution they gave and try to see how many other ways I could implement a counting system.

Comment: I am sure that both Perl and AWK are better to use in a long term more stable system, but I would rather stick with SED and Bash at least until I can wrap my head around a simple fundamental concept. If I brush it off and try other options, I feel like I am only limiting my own knowledge and experience. I don't want to quit, just understand the sed syntax. :)

Comment: `sed` should be able to increment either `Total Recordings:`, or `Total Recordings Today:` as you have it currently; is it not working? One thing I would recommend is getting rid of the old-style backticks ``` and using the newer `$( ... )` shell expansion syntax.

Comment: I just realized I am writing it out to only one file. I knew needed the coffee!!! Thank you on the backticks, will do for sure, I don't wanna start any bad habits.

Comment: All ears! I am eager to learn this.

Comment: This suffers from a race condition; if the file is updated by another process between the `cut` and the `sed`, you end up overwriting the result from that process. Doing it in a single Awk or Perl invocation would solve that problem, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` should work fine for doing increments on both `Total Recordings:`, or `Total Recordings Today:` in your file since it's looking for the same pattern. To reset it each day at a certain time I would recommend a cronjob.

```
0 0 * * * echo \"Total Recordings Today:0\" > /path/to/TotalCount.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The other things I would encourage is to use the newer style syntax `$( ... )` for the shell expansion, and create a variable for your `TotalCount.txt` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

totals=/path/to/TotalCount.txt
oldnum=$(cut -d ':' -f2 "$totals")
newnum=$((oldnum + 1))
sed -i "s/$oldnum\$/$newnum/g" "$totals"
```

This way you can easily reuse it for whatever else you want to do with it, quote it properly and simplfy your code. Note: on OS X sed inplace expansion would need to be `sed -i ''`.

Whenever in doubt, http://shellcheck.net is a really nice tool to help find mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 2):

although you're looking for a `sed` solution, cannot resist to post how it can be done in `awk`

```
$ awk -F: -v OFS=: '{$2++}1' file > temp && temp > file
```

`-F:` set the input field delimiter and `-v OFS=:` output field delimiter to `:`, `awk` parses the second field and increments by one, `1` is a shorthand for print (can be replaced with any "true" value); output will be written to a temp file and if successful will overwrite the original input file (to mimic in-place edit).

Answer (score 0):

Sed is a fine tool, but notoriously not the best for arithmetic. You could make what you already have work by initializing the counter to zero prior to incrementing it, if the file was not last modified today (or does not exist):

```
[ `date +%Y-%m-%d` != "`stat --printf %z TotalCount.txt 2> /dev/null|cut -d ' ' -f 1`" ] && echo "Total Recordings Today:0" > TotalCount.txt
```

To do same with shifts, you would likely calculate shift "ordinal number" by subtracting first shift start since midnight (say 7 * 3600) from seconds since epoch (which is a midnight) and dividing by length of shift (8 * 3600) and initialize the counter if that changes. Something like:

```
[ $(((`date +%s` - 7 * 3600) / (8 * 3600))) -gt $(((`stat --printf %Z TotalCount.txt 2> /dev/null` - 7 * 3600) / (8 * 3600))) ] && echo "Total Recordings This Shift:0" > TotalCount.txt
```